# Power load and source questions (music controller with led strip load)

Tags: power

[image]

This is power source (a music controller) for a project
[image]
This LED strip is a 72WATT load. My power calculations are 216W-72W=144W. So I have 144w remaining to use (thats my understanding) 
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

How did they used this kind of adapter if they are short with 12watts?

2nd question: If A power device can source more watts than (mine with 216w). Could I use two loads (like an led strip) at the same time?

3rd question: What if a source has lower watts than the load?

Comment: Please use proper punctuation, formatting and grammar.

Comment: I think you will be fine controlling two 60 W LED strips. It has two connectors for it and although it says it can supply up to 18 A, I think you should plan on it being able to provide up to 6 A at each connector and no more. And since you only need 5 A for each strip (two), looks like it will work okay. (Assuming it's not otherwise poorly designed or poorly implemented, of course. It is always buyer-beware.)

Comment: @jonk -- OP also refers to another PSU that powers this device. This other PSU is rated at 60W while the LED strips are rated as 74W.

Comment: @WesleyLee I see the OP saying 216 W. However, that number seems to be taken straight from the pictured device that I think he is calling "mine." It's not a source, of course, and instead needs one. I'm not sure the OP's question is the one you imagine. But it may be, too. I honestly can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw youtube channel they used this power adapter with RGB strip. The question remain in my head, how did they used this kind of adapter if they are short with 12Watts?

The one on the youtube channel you saw probably worked because:

1) there is quite a voltage drop on these strips, so the LEDs near the end use a bit less power;

2) they only draw max current when fully on (Red, Green and Blue 100%), so any RGB color you use (Say purple: red and blue only) is going to draw less than 72W.

> 2nd question: if watts in adapter does not care since my music controller support with 216w. Can I buy 2 RGB strip with 72w and use same time?

Your PSU has to supply more energy than your system draws. So you can't use a 60W PSU to supply 144W of LEDs, even if something in the middle can handle 216W.

**Bottom line:**

If I were you, I'd just buy a PSU that can handle more than what your controller can (say 12V 20A) and call it a day.

Comment: thanks, but i dont get the first answer clearly. can i use my adapter with this strip? im planning single strip first since i alraedy have the adapter and upgrade my PSU in the future for more strip.

Comment: Depending on what colors you use you will either be fine or stress the PSU too much. If you are really in a rush you'll probably be fine if you don't use "white" (100% RGB). I personally wouldn't do it, I always like plenty of headroom in PSUs, especially if they are the cheap Chinese ones.

Comment: One last thing what does CHANNEL mean?

Comment: @MarkPawl -- each 'color' is a channel R, G, B = 3 channels